# Spring service server receives streaming responses from the FastAPI AI server and forwards them to frontend

Tags: spring-boot, http, streaming

I have two servers, service server with Spring Boot (Java) and FastAPI AI server. The AI server has an API that responds with text streaming (content-type of `text/event-stream`). Workflow is like below.

1. Client sends post request to Spring server and spring server checks authentication and creates post request body for AI server.
2. Spring server sends post request to AI server and gets text streaming response.
3. Spring server responds to client with same response from AI server (text streaming).

I want to know, if there is simple way to accomplish the task I want.

I tried with Flux response first.

```java
@PostMapping(value = "/streaming", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
public Flux<String> streamTest() throws Exception {
    WebClient client = WebClient.builder()
            .baseUrl("http://localhost:8000/aichat_dummy")
            .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            .build();
    Flux<String> eventStream = client.post()
            .accept(MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToFlux(String.class);
    return eventStream;
}
```

And I also test `RestResponse`:

```java
@PostMapping(value = "/streaming", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
public RestResponse<Flux<ServerSentEvent<String>>> streamTest() throws Exception {
    ParameterizedTypeReference<ServerSentEvent<String>> type = new ParameterizedTypeReference<>() {};
    WebClient client = WebClient.builder()
        .baseUrl("http://192.168.0.130:8000/aichat_dummy")
        .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        .build();

    Flux<ServerSentEvent<String>> eventStream = client.post()
        .accept(MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM)
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToFlux(type);

    HttpHeaders headers = HttpHeaders.writableHttpHeaders(HttpHeaders.EMPTY);
    headers.add("Transfer-Encoding", "chunked");
    headers.add("Content-Type", "text/event-stream; charset=utf-8");

    return new ResponseEntity<>(eventStream, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

These codes request to AI server normally, but can't respond as streaming to the client.

Answer (score 0):

You can try returning it using `SseEmitter`. like this:

```java
@PostMapping("/test-stream")
public SseEmitter testStreamChat(@RequestBody @Validated Input input) throws Exception{
    SseEmitter sseEmitter = new SseEmitter();
    ChatRequest chatRequest = new ChatRequest(input.getInput(), null);
    try (CloseableHttpAsyncClient client = HttpAsyncClientBuilder.create().build()){
        SimpleHttpRequest simpleHttpRequest = SimpleRequestBuilder.post(streamChatUrl)
                .setBody(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(chatRequest), ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .build();
        client.start();
        Future<SimpleHttpResponse> future = client.execute(SimpleRequestProducer.create(simpleHttpRequest),
                new AbstractCharResponseConsumer<>() {

                    @Override
                    protected void start(HttpResponse response, ContentType contentType) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    protected SimpleHttpResponse buildResult() {
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void releaseResources() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    protected int capacityIncrement() {
                        return 1;
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void data(CharBuffer src, boolean endOfStream) {
                        while (src.hasRemaining()) {
                            char c = src.get();
                            try {
                                sseEmitter.send(SseEmitter.event().data(c));
                            } catch (IOException ioException) {
                                log.error("sse send error", ioException);
                            }
                        }
                        if (endOfStream) {
                            try {
                                sseEmitter.send(SseEmitter.event().data("[DONE]"));
                            } catch (IOException ioException) {
                                log.error("sse send error", ioException);
                            }finally {
                                sseEmitter.complete();
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }, null);
        future.get();
    }
    return sseEmitter;
}
```

update: `CloseableHttpAsyncClient` from apache's httpclient5 and httpcore5 libraries.